# chrome.runtime.onMessage not executing correctly in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, getelementsbytagname

I am writing a program that, if you click the extension popup, will copy both your current text selection and URL of the page you're on into the input fields of another page with the tab ID 0. It is able to copy it, but the insertion fails. The insertion gets done in the fill.js script and should get triggered by a `chrome.runtime.onMessage` event. It receives the URL and selection text as the message itself. Then it should get a list of all input elements and fill their value with the first part of the message, the URL. I intend to change this later, but for now I just want the basic insertion to work. Why does fill.js do nothing?

### manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Annelp",
  "description": "An annotation helper!",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [{
    "js": ["fill.js"],
    "matches": ["file:///Users/myusername/Documents/annelp-main/test.html"]
  }],
  "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "tabs"],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "/images/get_started16.png",
    "32": "/images/get_started32.png",
    "48": "/images/get_started48.png",
    "128": "/images/get_started128.png"
  }
}
```

### popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="output"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

### popup.js

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript( {
  code: "window.getSelection().toString();"
}, function(selection) {
  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
    var tablink = tab.url;
    chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(function(tabs) {
      var annotab = tabs[0];
      var updateProperties = { 'active': true };
      chrome.tabs.update(annotab.id, updateProperties, function() {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(annotab.id, [selection[0], tablink]);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

### fill.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
    var allInputsElements = getElementsByTagName("input");
    allInputsElements.forEach(inputElement => inputElement.value = message[0])
});
```

### test.html (Page I test it on)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="url" />
        <input type="text" id="text" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Substitute `getElementsByTagName` for `document.getElementsByTagName`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I tried changing it to `document.getElementsByTagName`, but unfortunately it still doesn't work.